# How to install tensorflow 1.12 in Colab?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, installation, pip, google-colaboratory

I have been trying to run someone else's code in Colab and have been struggling with this for days now (I tried to avoid installing it's tensorflow version, but it seems to be necessary).

I obviously tried with:

```
!pip install tensorflow==1.12
```

But it says:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.12 (from versions: 1.13.1, 1.13.2, 1.14.0, 1.15.0, 1.15.2, 1.15.3, 1.15.4, 1.15.5, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.1.4, 2.2.0rc0, 2.2.0rc1, 2.2.0rc2, 2.2.0rc3, 2.2.0rc4, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.3.0rc0, 2.3.0rc1, 2.3.0rc2, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.3.3, 2.3.4, 2.4.0rc0, 2.4.0rc1, 2.4.0rc2, 2.4.0rc3, 2.4.0rc4, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.4.4, 2.5.0rc0, 2.5.0rc1, 2.5.0rc2, 2.5.0rc3, 2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.2, 2.6.0rc0, 2.6.0rc1, 2.6.0rc2, 2.6.0, 2.6.1, 2.6.2, 2.7.0rc0, 2.7.0rc1, 2.7.0, 2.8.0rc0)

> ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.12

I also tried with:

```
!pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.12.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

And got:

> ERROR: tensorflow-1.12.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Does anyone know which command(s) would work?

Comment: What version of python3 are you running? 1.2 should work with python 3.4 thru 3.6

Comment: I thought I was using 3.6.3 (the same of the original code), but I checked with   !python --version   and it's 3.7.12 (seems like my 3.6.3 installation isn't working). Could you help my with that, mate?

Comment: Not sure, I have no experience with colab. Maybe this example of installing python 3.5 will help: https://colab.research.google.com/github/Dene33/mlcourse.ai/blob/master/jupyter_english/tutorials/Useful_Google_Colab_snippets.ipynb

Comment: It helped. Thanks ✌

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to William D. Irons for helping. This is the code that I ended up with:

```
from IPython.display import clear_output
import time
!add-apt-repository --yes ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
!apt-get update
!apt-get install python3.6
!apt-get install python3.6-dev

!wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py && python3.6 get-pip.py
  
import sys

sys.path[2] = '/usr/lib/python36.zip'
sys.path[3] = '/usr/lib/python3.6'
sys.path[4] = '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload'
sys.path[5] = '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages'
sys.path[7] = '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/extensions'

!pip install tensorflow==1.12

clear_output()
time.sleep(1)

import os
os.kill(os.getpid(), 9) #(This automatically restarts the runtime so the changes take effect)
```

After the restart, you just run this:

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x
import sys
sys.path[3] = '/usr/lib/python36.zip'
sys.path[4] = '/usr/lib/python3.6'
sys.path[5] = '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload'
sys.path[6] = '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages'
sys.path[8] = '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/extensions'
!pip install tensorflow==1.12
from IPython.display import clear_output

import tensorflow as tf
clear_output()
print(tf.__version__) #(This is just to check that everything went right)
```

And you are ready to go. Hope it helps someone else with the same problem

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work anymore. print(tf.__version__) returns 1.15.2 all the time. Can you check the solution?

Comment: I just checked it and you're right. Seems that the !pip install tensorflow==1.12 isn't working. Pretty weird. If you solve it, share your solution, pls